# How do I subtract TimeSpan and DateTime?

Tags: c#, webforms

I have placed a countdown timer which shows remaining time to complete the exam.

I am trying to calculate the total time taken by the user to complete the exam.

To calculate this, I subtracted the `end_time` of the exam with the remaining time shows in the countdown timer but I am getting current date in the output .For example `-09:04:05.1564371`...here it is the time when I ran the code.

I don't know where I am making mistake. Have a look at my code show me where I am making mistake and what is the solution.

**Examdemo.aspx.cs :-**

```
public partial class Student_Examdemo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack || Session["end_t"] == null)
        {
             DateTime start_time = DateTime.Now;
             DateTime end_time = start_time.AddMinutes(3);
             Session["end_t"] = end_time;
        } 
    }

    protected void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         DateTime dt = (DateTime)Session["end_t"];
         DateTime dt_curr = DateTime.Now;
         TimeSpan ts = dt - dt_curr;
         lblTimer.Text = ts.Hours.ToString() + ":" + ts.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + ts.Seconds.ToString();

         if (ts.Minutes == 0)
         {
             timer1.Enabled = false;
             Response.Redirect("/Student/Result.aspx");
         }

        TimeSpan usedTime = ts.Subtract(dt.TimeOfDay); //calculating the total time taken by user
        Session["takentime"] = usedTime.ToString(); //storing the calculated time in the session
    }

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //statements

        Response.Redirect("/Student/Result.aspx?Score=" + Label2.Text +"&AttemptedQues=" +Label3.Text+ "&CorrectAns=" +Label4.Text);
    }
}
```

**Result.aspx.cs :-**

```
public partial class Student_Result : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["Score"];
        Label2.Text = Request.QueryString["AttemptedQues"];
        Label3.Text = Request.QueryString["CorrectAns"];
        Label5.Text = Session["takentime"] as string; //displaying the calculated time...got output like this : '-09:04:05.1564371'
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the configuration of the timer? Is it wise to use Session? I would place this data in a database.

Comment: Logically, you cannot find out the time taken without either: Knowing the start time or: Knowing the maximum duration allowed. Store `start_time` in the session variable (or as Jeroen suggests, the database) and then your duration will be `(DateTime.Now - startTime)`. Your code, currently, will be giving you `(timeLeft - (currentTime - lastMidnight))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow figured out the problem and here is the solution:

Store the Start Time in a session as

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack || Session["end_t"] == null)
    {
        DateTime start_time = DateTime.Now;
     Session["start_t"] = start_time; 
        DateTime end_time = start_time.AddMinutes(3);
        Session["end_t"] = end_time;
    }
```

and Find the difference in the timer event

```
DateTime dtstart = (DateTime)Session["start_t"];
    TimeSpan timeUsed = DateTime.Now - dtstart;
    TimeSpan removeMillSeconds = new TimeSpan(timeUsed.Days, timeUsed.Hours, timeUsed.Minutes, timeUsed.Seconds, 0);
    Session["takentime"] = removeMillSeconds.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Following line is wrong..in your code.

```
TimeSpan usedTime = ts.Subtract(dt.TimeOfDay); //calculating the total time taken by user
```

`ts` is already containing difference of time like `00:02:59.9919920`...

and then after you are subtract it with  `end_time.TimeOfDay` which can be like `04:20:53.7564800`

So the difference is wrong, it is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the time taken in milliseconds, you don't need to do this much.

```
(dtend - dtstart).TotalMilliseconds
```